# Unable to use registerlistener with sensormanager in android

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am working in Android studio. i have a class named MyThread which extends thread and implements SensorEventListener.

```
private final SensorManager mSensorManager=       (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
private final Sensor mAccelerometer=   mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

and when i try to access method registerlistener with mSensormanager its showing an error:

> cannot resolve symbol registerlistener

I amn't able to know why it's not able to access. i tried googling it but in vain. please help me out.

Comment: there is code missing here (how do you registerlistener?), But it seems you are triyng to register a listener from a class which cannot do that. the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html says register listener needs also a context, which i don't think you provide in your thread class.

Comment: Yes absolutely the answer what i was looking for @N Dorigatti . i have read that before and i was stuck at this point. but still there is a small doubt. registerlistener no where needed a context to be passed into it and there is also nowhere specified that it should be used in methods which have context. after that i tried to use in OnCreate method and it was working. the link you gave also i wasn't able to find. Sorry if i am asking silly questions but it would be very grateful of you if you could guide me into that

Answer (score 3):

Create a SensorEventListener and pass it to right method for registering.e.g.

```
  SensorEventListener _SensorEventListener=   new SensorEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

            }
        };
        mSensorManager.registerListener(_SensorEventListener , mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
```